Graceful labeling of the complete bipartite graph and its laplacian quadratic form diagonalized
A graceful labeling of a connected simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ is a map $f:V\to\lbrace 1,...,|E|+1\rbrace$ such that for all $t\in\lbrace 1,...,|E|\rbrace$ there is a (trivially unique) $\langle i,j\rangle\in E$ with $|f(i)-f(j)|=t$.
I am considering a complete bipartite graph $K_{a,b}$ with $a<b$. It is well known that $K_{a,b}$ has a graceful labeling $\lbrace 0,b,2b,...,b(a-1)\rbrace \sqcup\lbrace b(a-1)+1,b(a-1)+2,...,ab\rbrace$ where the union discribes the split of labels for each partition.
On the other hand, it can be proven, that in the case of $K_{a,b}$ the graceful labeling is the solution to the integer representation problem
$$Q_{K_{a,b}}(x_1,...,x_{a+b})=x^TLx=\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle\in E} (x_i-x_j)^2=\sum_{j=1}^{ab}j^2$$
where $L$ is the graph Laplacian of $K_{a,b}$. Now, I know that any positive semi-definite quadratic form can be transformed into its diagonal form with its eigenvalues as coefficients. Additionally, as far as I know, under this congruence, representations of integers are preserved in the sense that if all entries of the representing $x$ are integers, so are the ones under the congruence transformation (I am lacking the source for this right now, if anyone could provide it, I would be glad.).
In this case, we can transform $Q_{K_{a,b}}$ into its diagonal form
$$Q_{K_{a,b}}^D(y_0,y_a^{(1)},..,y_a^{(b-1)},y_b^{(1)},..,y_b^{(a-1)})=(a+b)y_0^2+a\sum_{j=1}^{b-1}(y_a^{(j)})^2+b\sum_{j=1}^{a-1}(y_b^{(j)})^2$$
by congruence $D=P^TLP$ where $P$ is some non-singular matrix. I am, finally, interested in the form of the labels of the graceful labeling given above after transformation under $P$.
Hence, I want to find such a $P$ explicitly for the case of the complete bipartite graph. I derived a general formula for a transformation matrix $S$ such that $D=S^{-1} L S$ is diagonal and by Gram-Schmidt, one can obtain directly the orthogonal matrix $T$ such that $D=T^TL T$.
Is it possible to go from this formula to finding $P$? And if not, is it already known or which approach could get me there?

Yes, just take $P=T$. In general, congruence preserves only inertia, but since you want $D$ as a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $L$, you need to preserve eigenvalues and not just their signs, so you want $P$ orthogonal.
In the case of non-degenerate eigenvalues the orthogonalization used to calculate $T$ can be done in different ways and so $T$ or $P$ is not unique.
The rest of the answer is more to do with how to find the $y$ values and whether or not they are integer.
To find a set of $y_{i}$ from the $x_{i},$ note that
$$Q=y^{T}Dy=x^{T}Lx=x^{T}TDT^{T}x$$
so taking
$$y=T^{T}x$$
gives a solution. For example, for $a=1,b=2$ the eigenvalues are $0,1,3,$ $Q=5,$ $
x=[0,1,2]^{T},$ $y=[y_{00},y_{a}^{(1)},y_{0}]^{T}=[\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{6}
/2]^{T}$ and the diagonal form is
$$0\cdot \left( \sqrt{3}\right) ^{2}+1\cdot \left( \sqrt{2}/2\right)
^{2}+3\cdot \left( \sqrt{6}/2\right) ^{2}=5$$
The $y$ values are not integer and it is easy to see that there is no
integer solution to
$$1\cdot \left( y_{a}^{(1)}\right) ^{2}+3\cdot \left( y_{0}\right) ^{2}=5$$
so integer solutions cannot be expected in the general case. It is possible
to say more about when the $y_{i}$ calculated in this way may be integer or
rational by considering the known form (for complete bipartite graphs) of the matrix $T$ of the
orthogonalized eigenvectors of $L$.  In the
case of non-degenerate eigenvalues the orthogonalization can be done in
different ways and so $T$ is not unique, and so there is some freedom to
search for integer solutions.

I am trying to find $P$ to diagonalize using congruence as discussed for example here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329304/find-a-basis-with-respect-to-which-this-bilinear-form-is-diagonal

My answer did have $P=T$, but much later. I've now moved that to the beginning. I'm sorry, I thought you were asking about more than just that, since you already had both $D = P^TLP$ and $D = T^TLT$
